# Excel VBA click prematurely ends calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm applying a bunch of countifs to a range of cells within a long chain of opening/closing a few books, pulling data etc.

`ws_DAT.Range("C6:C" & lROW1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Database'!A:A,'DAT'!A6,'Database'!D:D,""Flagged"")"`

There's a few problems with this -

If I click anywhere on Excel, the COUNTIF calculation stops and the vba code skips to the next line so I end up with a bunch of zeros as a result - **Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?**

Also, when doing this manually in Excel it's a LOT quicker even though in the code I've got screenupdating set to false - and if I do it manually I can see Excels "Calculating" up to 100% but when doing this via macro it doesn't show - **is there any way to show the calc %**

Is there a better way to apply the same logic to my cells?

Comment: Maybe you also turn off automatic calculation and disable events

Comment: @Storax is right, try that. Anyway, why would you want to do any actions on workbook while it's being updated by your code??

Comment: I haven't touched automatic calculation but I did disable events - an even stranger thing I noticed is when I step through this code line by line, the calculations are just as quick as manual - but the whole process left unattended is extremely slow! What is going on?!?!

Comment: I don't want any actions to happen while it's being updated! It's a long running code - if I click anywhere within excel when it's running (by mistake e.g.), it skips the COUNTIFS calculating properly - I'd like to prevent this and let the code run its course uninterrupted

Comment: Block the user by using `Application.Interactive = False`

Comment: I guess Rory has the right answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

You can force the sheet to calculate with `ws_DAT.Calculate`, or the column to update with `ws_DAT.Columns(3).Calculate`, and the macro will not progress until it has finished.

You can probably also speed up the calculations *and* prevent the values being 0 with this code:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws_DAT.Range("C6:C" & lROW1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Database'!A:A,'DAT'!A6,'Database'!D:D,""Flagged"")"
ws_DAT.Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Generally, unless writing a very short & fast macro, I find there are few reasons not to set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start of the code and back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.  Setting `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` for the duration of the macro is another good way to speed things up